# Changing panel control size properties

Tags: c#, winforms

I have being working with a size of a panel control. While running the size change but the size properties of the panel control doesn't. It stays the same size. Is there a way to change the size value properties using code?

```
private void listFormats_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        var w = dtFormats.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["Desc"].ToString() == listFormats.SelectedItem.ToString()).Select(x => int.Parse(x["width"].ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
        var h = dtFormats.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["Desc"].ToString() == listFormats.SelectedItem.ToString()).Select(x => int.Parse(x["height"].ToString())).FirstOrDefault();
        txtH.Text = h.ToString();
        txtW.Text = w.ToString();
        Statics st = new Statics();
        panelDesign.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(st.inchTopx(int.Parse(txtW.Text)), st.inchTopx(int.Parse(txtH.Text)));            
        panelControl2.Width = st.inchTopx(int.Parse(txtW.Text));
        panelControl2.Height = st.inchTopx(int.Parse(txtH.Text));
        panelDesign.Location = new Point((splitDesigner.Panel2.Width / 2) - (panelDesign.Size.Width / 2) + 5, (splitDesigner.Height / 2) - (panelDesign.Height / 2));
        panelControl2.Location = new Point((splitLabelSize.Panel2.Width / 2) - (panelControl2.Size.Width / 2) + 5, (splitLabelSize.Height / 2) - (panelControl2.Height / 2));
    }
```

I try a sizechanged event, resize event, layout event and putting the panelDesign.Size code in a button but I just can make it work.

Comment: Hi darksaky, do you have any code or images of the issue that you can show?

Comment: The code is very long and is not organized at all. But I can show you at least the part that we are trying to change the size.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't have any AutoSize or Dock properties?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? In general I find it rare to set the size manually, and even more rare to set it according to text-field input. The usual way would be to either auto-size according to content,or scale with the parent control.

Comment: The program is to create labels. That's why is being manually.

Comment: Are you dynamically building the user interface of your form?

Comment: if you mean the panel control? no.